# How can I get the values ​of all the specified properties in JSON by using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I am new to jq and facing an issue while parsing my JSON
I have a JSON like this

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Found On:"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Name of component"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "The Problem:"
        },
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "content": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "text": "Description of the problem"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to get values of all “text” attributes. However, it can be seen that this JSON is a multi-layered nested structure.
So how could I achieve my
expected result:

```
Found On:
Name of component
The Problem:
Description of the problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man jq`:

> ## ..
>
> Short-hand for recurse without arguments. This is intended to resemble the XPath `//` operator.  Note  that `..a`  does  not work; use `..|a` instead. In the example below we use `..|.a?` to find all the values of object keys "a" in any object found "below" `.`.
>
> ```
> jq '..|.a?'
>    [[{"a":1}]]
> => 1
> ```

All you need to do is tweaking the example above a bit to suppress `null`s:

```
$ jq '..|(.text?)//empty' file
Found On:
Name of component
The Problem:
Description of the problem
```